# Cakephp 2.45 format text in input to include "-" between letters

Tags: cakephp, text, input, format

I have a need to make an input box formatted like so:
"x-x-xx-xxxxx"
So as they type the first x then it would appear as "x-" then the next entered would be "x-x-", and so on, kind of like a phone number.

Here is my current input:
Model:

```
function getAllFflNums($userIds=null) {
$ffls=array();
$cond = array();
$cond['UserFirearm.user_id']=$userIds;
if($userIds) {
$res = $this->find('list', array('conditions'=>$cond, 'fields'=>array('UserFirearm.received_ffl_number') ));
   foreach($res as $row) {
$ffls=$res;
   }
}
return $ffls;
}
```

Controller:

```
$conditions = array();
if ($userId) {
$conditions['UserFirearm.user_id'] = $userId;
}
$sel_rffl=array();
$sel_rffl = $this->UserFirearm->getAllFflNums($this->request->data['UserFirearm']   ['user_id'] = $userId);
$this->set(compact('sel_rffl'));`
```

and my view:

```
echo $this->Form->input('received_ffl_number', array(
'empty' => 'enter a vaild ffl number',
'label' => 'FFL Number',
'options'=> $sel_rffl,
'id' => 'received_ffl_number',
));
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Jeff

Comment: If you want this to happen while the user is typing, then of course this has to happen client-side – meaning: JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want this to happen on the fly, you will need to use JavaScript. So you should only do this if you want the user to visually see the dashes for convenience, don't use it to have the data saved like that in your database (you should use data molding in the `beforeSave` method of your Model if that is what you want to achieve). A JavaScript solution (using jQuery) would look something like this:

```
$('#received_ffl_number').keyup(function(event) {
  // Add dashes after the 1st, 3rd and 6th letter/digit
  if (
    $('#received_ffl_number').val().length == 1 ||
    $('#received_ffl_number').val().length == 3 ||
    $('#received_ffl_number').val().length == 6
  ) {
      // Unless the pressed key is backspace or delete, append a dash
      if (event.which != 8 && event.which != 46) {
          $(this).val($(this).val() + "-");
      }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that was quick and insightful helped a ton